# How to emit actions before and after a promise observable -- Redux Observable (rxjs6)

Tags: async-await, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I want to dispatch an action, `fetchData`, to get data from my API and store it in my redux store by dispatching the action `setData`. I was able to do this with the following epic:

```
export const FetchDataEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter((action) => action.type === fetchData.type),
    switchMap(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        return api
          .getData()
          .then((result) => {
            resolve(setData({ data: result.data }))
          })
          .catch((e) => resolve(setData({ data: undefined })))
        resolve(setData({ data: undefined }))
      })
    })
  )
```

Although I don't think this is a good solution, I couldn't find a better one that actually worked in rxjs6 so if you know of a better way of doing this, please let me know! Anyway, now I want to dispatch an action `setLoading(true)` before the data is fetched, and `setLoading(false)` once the data has been fetched so that a loading screen can be displayed on the front-end. I was able to emit the `setLoading(false)` after the data is fetched by doing what's in the epic below, but if I tried emitting `setLoading(true)` before the `switchMap`, the `switchMap` never emits anything and all that gets emitted is the `setLoading(true)`.

```
export const FetchDataEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter((action) => action.type === fetchData.type),
    // adding this line prevents the switchMap from emitting anything
    // map(()=>setLoading(true)),
    switchMap(() =>
      from(
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          return api
            .getData()
            .then((result) => {
              resolve(result.data)
            })
            .catch((e) => resolve(data))
          resolve(data)
        })
      ).pipe(flatMap((data) => [setData({ data }), setLoading(false)]))
    )
  )
```

Isn't it supposed to just emit the `setLoading` action and then go on to the next `switchMap`? The `switchMap` works on its own so why does adding the `map` before it prevent it from emitting? I'm pretty new to redux-observable and rxjs so maybe I'm way off with my solution but please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: `map()` used in this way should not prevent `switchMap` from execution so the problem won't be in `map()` itself but it's hard to give any advice from just this. Btw, why you think `siwtchMap` doesn't emit anything?

Comment: @martin I had the Redux Devtools open and wasn't seeing the action that the `switchMap` was supposed to emit. I just tried again and noticed that the action that `map` is supposed to emit isn't emitting now (but the `switchMap` action was emitting)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try simplify you stream as below see if it works?  Using `tap` for side effects - `setLoading` then it won't intervene with your stream. switchMap will also take a promise like return value so you don't really need to wrap it in a `from` and `Promise` constructor

```
  action$.pipe(
    filter((action) => action.type === fetchData.type),
    tap(()=>setLoading(true)),
    switchMap(() =>api.getData()),
    switchMap(data => setData({ data }),
    tap(()=>setLoading(false)),
   )
```

Comment: returning the data within the `switchMap` results in the error `You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.`. It also doesn't look like `tap` emits the action `setLoading(true)` either :/

Comment: what is the function signature of setData and setLoading?